# regex to validate selected list of punctuations

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to take user input on the list of punctuations allowed in a string and then match the string for occurance of those punctuations.

E.g: User enters "@#$%^&". Need to validate :

1. User cannot repeat punctuations in the 'allowed punctuations' box.E.g: cannot use "%%$#@".
2. If the user entered password contains only those punctuations and no other punctuations.

Also, this needs to be multi-language safe.

Thanks,
Beginner at Regex

**Added:**

Language i'm using is c#. Need to put this in a data annotation on MVC Model property.

I did get the ability to filter the regex to allow only punctuations by using : "^(?![0-9])(?![a-zA-Z])\p{P}+$"

However, i was unable to get the regex to find duplicate punctuations.

Comment: Can I ask, why would you limit the punctuations _allowed_ in a password? Surely they should be able to enter whatever they like, the more crazy the better?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem well. Use the regex `[.,:;']`. If you have other punctuations to match, list them in the square parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

As far s you didn't specify language, i implemented example in PHP:

```
$s = 'hello %wo$rl@@d';
$r = '~([@#\$%\^&]).*?(?=\1)~';

if (preg_match_all($r, $s, $m)) {
  // password is invalid
}
```

If condition will be satisfied if one of allowed punctuation chars are repeating in remaining part of the input $s.